# java web start app on localhost using WAMP is not able to run php scripts?

Tags: java, php, wamp, java-web-start

I have a signed java web start app that has been running on a server for many years. I have a need to create a version that I can run on a local machine. I have setup WAMP and the database and confirmed that these work by accessing through php scripts via localhost. My java program is also launching but there is a problem when it tries to access a local php file through locahost. Nothing is returned. I call php scripts that access the database from within the java app. Am i missing something fundamental here? ANy help appreciated. Thanks

Comment: If I recall correctly you JWS security requires you to use the same name of the server as used inside the JNLP file.

Comment: Are there any stack traces?  Is the code ignoring exception output?  Be sure the [Java Console](http://www.java.com/en/download/help/javaconsole.xml) is configured to show.  If there is no output at the default level, raise the level and try it again.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for the responses. The problem has been solved. I forgot to turn off deprecation and other warnings so what I was getting back from the php scripts was not what I expected. Once I turned off the warnings everything functioned as expected. To sum up, I am serving up a java web start app through localhost, executing php scripts from within the java app that manipulate an sql database, and return the results to the java app. 
Thanks again,
greg

Answer (score 0):

Well are you using Quercus ? It would have been easier to suggest a solution if you had mentioned how you are running php scripts in java app.

Basic thing here is you should always call your php file using classpath or path associated within the project

```
PHP php = new PHP("classpath:/com/demo/phpfile.php");
```

or sometimes you could use(os path if set up correctly) path of file as accessed by you operating system.

```
C:\websites\www\myproject\phpfile.php(example windows path)
```

if you are accessing files like http://localhost/myproject/phpfile.php
then the php file is executed by the wamp server and html output returned. so you do not get the php script.

If you are trying to run java inside php then you could call php files in the manner   http://localhost/myproject/phpfile.php to see the end result.